# AppCompactImageView Leak Canary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using Leak Canary to detect leak memory on my app. mLogoImage is an ImageView, and it leaks because it's referencing PhoneWindow I think.
Maybe this is related to (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171190). This is the log:

```
D/LeakCanary: * android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView has leaked:
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.mContentObserver
D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$SettingsObserver.this$0
D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.mContext
D/LeakCanary: * references com.example.MyActivity.mLogoImage
D/LeakCanary: * leaks android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instance
D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 307116d2-da30-4dbd-a105-74d0ea1c4361
```

Any guess how to solve this?